# Join 2 postgres sql queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join two Postgres queries for a The foreman report.
I am trying to see which servers are assigned to puppet class 180

The first Query is:

```
select puppetclass_id , host_id from host_classes where puppetclass_id = 180
```

the results look as follows

```
 puppetclass_id | host_id 
----------------+---------
            180 |     378
            180 |     377
```

The Second Query is:

```
select id, name, operatingsystem_id, enabled from public.hosts
```

the results look as follows:

```
 id  |            name             | operatingsystem_id | enabled 
-----+-----------------------------+--------------------+---------
 404 | s4-somedevserver- 4r5       |                 17 | t
 411 | mob-omedevserver- 4r2       |                 19 | t
```

I am trying to match the host_id of the first query and the id of the second query together, but remove duplicates.
I have the below query, but it just displayes all our servers and not only servers matching puppetclass 180

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name, operatingsystem_id
FROM
  (SELECT puppetclass_id , host_id
   FROM host_classes
   WHERE puppetclass_id = 180) t
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT id, name, operatingsystem_id, enabled
   FROM public.hosts) m
ORDER BY id
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want an `INNER JOIN` here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.*
FROM host_classes t1
INNER JOIN public.hosts t2
    ON t1.host_id = t2.id
WHERE
    t1.puppetclass_id = 180
ORDER BY t2.id;
```

You are currently doing a `CROSS JOIN` between the two tables, which will tend to give the cross product of all records from each table.

Comment: Perfect, working. thank you soo much for your assistance